# Is there a function to select a new cell in Google Sheets using Google-Apps-Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need google sheets to select a specific cell (B3) when a function (makeActive) is called. The cell should be selected as if a user has clicked on the cell themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as [the docs says](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setcurrentcellcell):

```
// The code below sets the cell B5 in the first sheet as the current cell.
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange('B5');
SpreadsheetApp.setCurrentCell(cell);

var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getSelection();
// Current cell: B5
var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
```